# export individual pages of markdown file to pdf

Tags: pandoc

Currently I have a markdown file that contains 30 pages. I would like to output only from page 3 to page 11 to pdf format.

I don't know which parameter will let `pandoc` output only pages from page 3 to page 11 of markdown file to pdf.

Could you guide me a real example of `pandoc` command line to output individual pages of markdown to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You can export all pages to pdf, and edit the exported pdf file and delete all pages you don't want.

Comment: So this means pandoc has no parameter to output individual pages to pdf?

Comment: I don't find any parameter to control pages range, maybe, you can have a try with `-file-scope` but I don't think it might meet your requirements. Anyway, before conversion, `pandoc` itself cannot know where is the right position for the n-page start and end. I had a similar need like yours before, and I converted all then delete pages no need.

Comment: Or, a better idea, edit source file, save the part which you want to transform to pdf pages to a separate file， and convert it.